# Exception When Others Then Not Catching ORA Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, exception

My 'Exception when others then' block isn't catching an error when trying to update a table that doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

```
BEGIN

UPDATE made_up_table
SET made_up_column = 1;

exception 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line('123');
end;
```

Comment: Expception handling is meant to catch runtime errors, while your code has "compile" errors: your code is not executed at all, so the exception block does not work.

Comment: Maybe Oracle SQL Developer simply doesn't show the output of `dbms_output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to use a non existing table, you get a compile-time error, not a run-time error.
For example, here you have no exception Handling:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2
  3  UPDATE made_up_table
  4  SET made_up_column = null;
  5
  6  exception
  7  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  8      dbms_output.put_line('123');
  9  end;
 10  /
UPDATE made_up_table
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 8:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

If you create the table with a not null constraint

```
SQL> create table made_up_table(made_up_column number not null);

Table created.

SQL> insert into made_up_table values (0);

1 row created.
```

and then you try to do an update that violates the constraint, you have an exception raised, and your error message shown:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2
  3  UPDATE made_up_table
  4  SET made_up_column = null;
  5
  6  exception
  7  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  8      dbms_output.put_line('123');
  9  end;
 10  /
123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Excellent, I've tried wrapping the update within an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and this is now handled, which makes sense. I've the slight problem now that the SQLERRM I've returned from the exception is stating 'ORA-00911: invalid character' upon running but I suppose that is unavoidable (and unimportant for this task if I'm honest)